# python - if statement and list index outside of range

Tags: python

I have a csv file with a 1st part made up of 3 entries and 2nd part made up of 2 entries. I want to isolate the data made up of 3 entries.

i wrote the following:

```
filename=open("datafile.txt","r")
data_3_entries_list=[]

 for line in filename:
    fields=line.split(",")
    if fields[2] == 0:
        break
    else:
        data_3_entries_list.extend(line)
```

i get the error message:
if fields[2] == 0 :
IndexError: list index out of range
     print(data_3_entries_list)

I also tried with if fields[2] is None but i get the same error.
I dont understand why im getting this error?

Comment: you should probably test the length of fields first e.g. `if len(fields) >= 3`

Comment: can you provide the csv file please?

Comment: I originally stated a length of 2 it should be 3 as indices are `0` based

Comment: I would agree, test the length of the list. Also, you should probably close the file when you're done.

Comment: @Edchum I changed it to what you said and now nothing happens when I run it

Comment: I don't know what you did but just needed to add a check: `if len(fields) >=3:  if fields[2] == 0:
        break
    else:
        data_3_entries_list.extend(line)`

Comment: or you can do `if len(fields) > 2 and fields[2] == 0: break`

Comment: @Hannah how can you successfully run your program then if you don't even have the file? from what do you know that your program causes an error?

Comment: I did it now I dont get an error but it prints the whole data without getting rid of the 2 entry ones..

Comment: @a_guest I have the file i just cant provide it online

Comment: @Hannah Maybe you can create a short example file out of this file which still reproduces the problem and add it to you question? So it is clear what you exactly have to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

Use len() or str.count()

```
for line in filename:
    fields=line.split(",")
    if len(fields) == 3:
        data_3_entries_list.append(line)

for line in filename:
    if fields.count(",") == 2:
        data_3_entries_list.append(line)
```

Comment: although at the end of each line in the list i get /n what does it mean? @xxyzzy

Comment: I suppose that /n represents end-of-line, whereas Python uses \n.  You would have to use string.replace().

Answer (score 1):

There is no implicit value for non-existent elements of a list; if `fields` only has 2 items, then `fields[2]` simply does not exist and will produce an error.

Check the length of the list explicitly:

```
if len(fields) == 3:
    break
data_3_entries_list.append(line)  # You may want append here, not extend
```

Answer (score 0):

If i have a csv file like this one, then this can work out

```
 with open('datafile.csv', 'w') as p:
    p.write("Welcome,to,Python")
    p.write("Interpreted,Programming,Language")

 filename=open("datafile.csv","r")
 data_3_entries_list=[]

 for line in filename:
    fields=line.split(",")
    if fields[2] == 0:
        break
    else:
        data_3_entries_list.extend(line)
```

Otherwise you'd have to atleast show us or me how your csv file is formatted.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because you're trying to get the value of an index that may not exist. There's a better way to do this, though.

Instead of testing the length outright, you can also use a split to see if the index exists. A list that isn't `len(a_list) >= 3` will simply return an empty list.

```
>>> mylist = range(3) #this list is [0, 1, 2]
>>> mylist[2:]
[2]

>>> mylist = range(2) #however THIS list is [0, 1]
>>> mylist[2:]
[]
```

In this way you can use the pythonic `if a_list: do_work()` to test if you even want to work with the data. This syntax is generally preferred to `if len(a_list) == value: do_work()`.

```
filename=open("datafile.txt","r")
data_3_entries_list=[]

 for line in filename:
    fields=line.split(",")
    if fields[2:]:  ##use a split to verify that such a split yields a result
        data_3_entries_list.extend(line)
```